# How to check if the quadratic congruence has solution or not

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratics

How to check if the quadratic congruence has solution or not, for example check:
$$x^2\equiv 1141 \pmod{2020}$$

I use Euler's Criterion but it doesn't work:
$$1141^\dfrac{2020-1}{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{2020}$$ Because $\dfrac{2020-1}{2}$ is a decimal number. Any hints would be great!

Comment: The euler criterion only applies for odd primes...

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. How can I do it with even numbers?

Comment: The only even prime is $2$; $2020$ is not prime.

Comment: I'm too sleepy, sorry for making errors! I have edited my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, since $2020=20\cdot 101$, it is enough to check whether the equation has roots modulo $20$ and $101$.

Modulo $20$: $x=1$ is a solution.

Modulo $101$: The equation is $x^2\equiv 30\pmod{101}$. Now, the quadratic residue is
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{30}{101}\right)&=\left(\frac{2}{101}\right)\left(\frac{3}{101}\right)\left(\frac{5}{101}\right)\\
&=(-1)^{\frac{101^2-1}8}\left(\frac{101}{3}\right)\left(\frac{101}{5}\right)\\
&=(-1)(-1)1\\
&=1.
\end{align}

Thus, there is a solution.

P.S.: $x=139$ is a solution to the original congruence.

Comment: what do you mean by "Modulo $4,5$: $x=1$ is a solution"

Comment: By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, it is enough to check there are solutions for $x^2\equiv1141\pmod4$, $x^2\equiv 1141\pmod 5$, and $x^2\equiv 1141\pmod{101}$. I am saying $x=1$ is a solution for the equations $x^2\equiv1141\pmod4$ and $x^2\equiv 1141\pmod 5$.

Comment: $x\equiv9,11,19\bmod20$ are also solutions to $x^2\equiv1\bmod20$, though $x\equiv1$ suffices to make the point that solutions exist

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

$x^2\equiv 1141 mod (2020)$

$1141=163\times 7$

$2020=20\times 101$

$163^{100}=(163^{50})^2\equiv 1 mod (101)$

$7^{100}\equiv 1 mod (101)$

$1141^{100} \equiv 1 mod (101)$

$\phi (20)= 8$

$1141^8=(1141^4)^2 \equiv 1 mod (20)$

So $x^2\equiv 1 mod (2020)$

Which means there is a solution.